# SharePoint Library - Multiple Content Types - Each Type as a link on page to open document

Tags: infopath, content-type

I have a SharePoint library for multiple request types.  Each request type has it's own InfoPath form, which I published to the library as content types.  All that is working fine.  However, instead of having someone go to the "New Document" button on the ribbon and choose the appropriate doc type/InfoPath form, I would like to have links (which I will display as buttons on the page) for them to use.

I have done this on previous pages (both libraries and lists), but with only one document type/one list (which were not content types).  I just used the Id number for uploading a document.  I'm having a problem figuring out how to do this with multiple content types though.  I'm assuming the code would be a little different.  Also, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use the entire ID number for the content type (which I found on SPD).

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to just click the new item from the drop down and copy the corresponding URL to notepad. Then just build up a link list or buttons and use that for quick access. Often I use a Sharepoint list to hold the URLs and use  that to create a prettier interface.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not sure how that helps me create buttons/hyperlinks to all my content types.  I'm fairly new to SharePoint, and definitely am not a programmer.  Would you mind being more specific in your explanation?  Again, much appreciated!